# Initialize dependencies when needed in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular website with a lot external dependencies. Some of these dependencies are only used on one state and really not needed to be initiated at the initial loading of the page.

Is it possible to defer this loading?

Comment: Load the dependencies using a service. You can load the facebook libs using a service, and that way it only happens when the service is injected by angular.

Comment: this could technically be considered off topic if it starts getting links to off site libraries, however there is a library that handles this.  check out angular-lazyload on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

You could append the js files dynamically by creating a function that does the loading, and call it when wanted:

```
function loadjsfile(filename){
    //if filename is a external JavaScript file
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
}
```

The call:

```
loadjscssfile("myscript.js")
```

[Source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Comment: the problem here is that if these javascript files are angular modules or dependencies, angular won't know they exist when they are loaded, and won't be able to access them.

Comment: this does not answer the problem of lazy loading angular modules